# Array constructed by data taken from a file prints the scanner filepath

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, scanning

I hope you're doing good. I have this assgnment i have to do for my programming course(It's actually for the midterm exam) and part of it is this. I have a .dat file where some numbers are stored. The file looks like this:

123456/100
345678/45
145679/67
135678/32
635479/78
536274/24
986372/80
236580/91
214768/55
426148/13

Now then, I want to create some userse with the first number(before the slash) being the pin code and the second number(behing the slash) being the amount of money they have. I am using a scanner to read the file and then using split string to divide the strings and putting them into an array to test my file, but for some reason the array prints the filepath I have written in my scanner constructor. This is the code I have. It's testing code divided in 3 classes.

*Main Class:*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AddUsers user = new AddUsers();    
    }
}
```

Users class, has a contructor and setters and getters:

```
public class Users {

    String pin, balance;

    public Users(String pin, String balance){

    }

    public String getPin(){
        return pin;
    }

    public String getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin){
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public void setBalance(String balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

And finally the AddUsers class, who uses the scanner, reads the file and does the rest of the opperations:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class AddUsers  {

    Users user;
    String pin, balance;
    int total;
    Scanner scan;
    ArrayList<Users> UserList;

    public AddUsers() throws FileNotFoundException{
        scan = new Scanner("users.dat");
        UserList = new ArrayList();


        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            total++;
            user = new Users("0", "0");

            String tokens[] = scan.nextLine().split("/");
            String last = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
            System.out.println(last);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output i get

```
users.dat
```

So then, what do I do?I want it to print the numbers in the .dat file. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If it is an assignment you should do it by yourself... Anyway try to pass the content of file instead the name.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I have actuallly almost finished it, but I'm stuck at this part. I don't see anything wrong with asking for a little help. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a File Object to scanner:

```
File file = new File("users.dat");
scan = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Problem is, when I do it like that, I get a file not found Exception. I am running the program on netbeans btw, so i have placed the users.dat file in the src folder of the project.
So if I do
    `code`
    File file = new File("src\\users.dat"); 
    scan = new Scanner(file);

In the output it gives me a FileNotFoundException

Comment: You need to place the file in the correct location or just pass the full qualified ressource name.

Comment: I know, that is why I have placed under the src folder in netbeans, but for some reason, it gives a file not found exception... Thank you btw, this was definitely helpful, Once i get around the filepath I believe it will work.

Comment: Netbeans don't run class in src folder but in root folder

Comment: Yeah I have placed it in the root as well, but it still gives file not found... idk why

Comment: As I have said - put the file in the correct path where the running application would look for the file or use a full-qualified ressource. It does not help you discussing that it can not find it. Indication of a File not Found Exception is what it says: The file can not be found because it is not there where you tell it to be in your code. Maybe you should have a look at relative path and full qualified paths to understand the behaviour.